# Python - How to run a huggingface pipeline offline for the first time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

I have a python code that uses a Huggingface pipeline.

```
from transformers import pipeline
import pandas as pd

tqa = pipeline(task="table-question-answering", model="google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq")

table = pd.read.csv("table.csv")
table = table.astype(str)

query = ["who has the highest salary", "what is Brenden's tsrat date?"]

answers = tqa(table=table, query=query)
```

This code works fine from a computer that has unrestricted access to the internet. During first run, this code downloads the transformers and probably caches it. on subsequent run it does not download the files anymore.

But my problem is I need to make this program run in a restricted server environment that does not have internet connectivity.

I was able to install all the required libraries using offline .whl files, but the first time run is failing as it's not able to download the transformers.

I have tried `os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE']=1` but it will only work if those files are at least downloaded once in the system.

How can this be made to work? Can I download those files manually (if yes- how ?) and place it somewhere in the target server manually ?

Comment: In my case without internet connection script became super slow (waits for timeout I guess) but still works for already downloaded models and you are right it caches it here is the example /home/<USERNAME>/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--daryl149--llama-2-7b-chat-hf/snapshots/bbc9b373dacff93e600e4426f2b3d3dd264e90ed/pytorch_model-00001-of-00002.bin

Answer (score 2):

To being able to use a HuggingFace model without Internet connection, you should first clone the desired model repository into your working directory.

In order to clone the model you specified, just run:

```bash
git lfs install
git clone https://huggingface.co/google/tapas-base-finetuned-wtq
```

After the model is downloaded, you should be able to use the pipeline by using the path to the model repository as model name:

```py
pipe = pipeline(task="table-question-answering", model=<MODEL_REPOSITORY_PATH>)
```